# How can I add a row to a table in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, tablelayout, tablerow

I'm trying to add a row to a table programmatically. I have already created two rows manually in the xml file.

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private TableLayout table;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        
        table = findViewById(R.id.table);
        TableRow newRow = new TableRow(this);
        table.addView(newRow);
    }
}
```

**activitiy_main.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
<RelativeLayout
...
<TableLayout
    android:id="@+id/table"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/rounded_edittext_table"
    android:padding="20dp">

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="20dp">

        <EditText style="@style/EditTextStyle" />
        <EditText style="@style/EditTextStyle" />
        <EditText style="@style/EditTextStyle" />
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="20dp">

        <EditText style="@style/EditTextStyle" />
        <EditText style="@style/EditTextStyle" />
        <EditText style="@style/EditTextStyle" />
    </TableRow>

</TableLayout>
...
</RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

But instead of a new row, I get a new TableLayout:
[image]
[image]

Comment: You mean you have 2 TableLayouts after `table.addView(newRow);`?

Comment: Yes, as shown in the second to last image. But then again the new TableLayout doesn't show up in the layout inspector (last image).

Comment: If I remember you need to add `setLayoutParams()` on your TableRow before adding it.

Comment: This doesn't work either:   ```TableRow newRow = new TableRow(this);
        newRow.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
        table.addView(newRow);``` It results in the same thing.